# Verificar se Input::file existe Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Tenho uma classe criada por mim que faz upload de arquivos. Queria verificar se Input::file('imagem') existe, pois se ele não existir, não faz o upload da imagem.

Segue o meu codigo:

```
if(Input::has('name')){
    $file = Input::file('imagem');
    $uploadClass = new UploadFile();
    $uploadClass->setFile($file);
    $uploadClass->randomFileName();
    $uploadClass->setMaxFileSize(1048576);
    $uploadClass->setAcceptedExtensions(['jpg','jpeg','png','zip']);
    $uploadFeito = $uploadClass->uploadFile('uploads');

    if (!$uploadFeito) {
        return Redirect::back()
        ->with('alerta_erro', $uploadClass->getMessage())
        ->withInput();  
    }
}
```

Comment: você tentou fazer de que forma ?

Comment: Tentei usando Input::has('imagem') mas n funcionou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolvi o meu problema, no lugar de `Input::has('imagem')`, usar `Input::hasFile('imagem')`.